# Como transformar un string a un numero

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una optimización de código y estoy en el dilema de cual es la mejor forma de transformar un string a un numero, tengo 3 métodos de hacer por los cuales puedo elegir y quiero saber de su opinion a ayudarme a resolver este dilema.

Ejemplo: Tengo la siguiente declaración.

```
const value = "30"
```

Los métodos que tengo a mi alcance para transformar la cadena a un numero son:

- Usando el método `Number(value)`
- Agregando un `"+"` a la izquierda: `+value`
- Usando el método `parseInt(value)`

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con optimizar. Yo uso parseInt(), aunque las otras también son buenas.

Comment: @Bélgica Mas que optimizar, es con cual puedo mejorar el rendimiento de mi Aplicativo Web, son pequeños detalles pero estoy en el dilema de cual utilizar

Comment: Quizás te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53159572/14536183

Comment: Number() y parseInt() en cuánto rendimiento no tienen muchas diferencias. Radica más en su funcionamiento interno.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no deberías preocuparte tanto por el rendimiento, sino por comportamiento, a fin de cuentas, no hay gran diferencia según [esta prueba](http://phrogz.net/js/string_to_number.html).

Si tú tienes el control de los datos recibidos y estás seguro que siempre serán solo números, entonces no habrá problemas. Pero, si existe la posibilidad de que aparezcan otros caracteres, deberías forzar a que el resultado sea numérico, ya sea interpretado, o cero si algo falla, por ejemplo:

```
let numero = parseInt(cadena) || 0;
```

El operador lógico `||` devolverá el primer valor **[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy)**, es decir, cualquier valor que en una comparación booleana no devuelva falso. Ante la presencia de valores interpretables como falso, devuelve el último elemento de la asignación.

```js
let val1 = '30';
let val2 = 'abc';  // En todos devuelve NaN
let val3 = '15a3'; // Solo parseInt() interpreta los primeros caracteres

// Función normal
function toNumber(str) {
    console.log(+str, Number(str), parseInt(str));
}
// Función con fallback (evitar errores)
function toNumber2(str) {
    console.log(+str || 0, Number(str) || 0, parseInt(str) || 0);
}

toNumber(val1);
toNumber(val2);
toNumber(val3);
toNumber2(val1);
toNumber2(val2);
toNumber2(val3);
```

Answer (score 0):

El operador unario `+` según la especificación EcmaScript 2021, utiliza la función abstracta `toNumber`, que también es utilizada por `Number` pero no por `parseInt`. Por lo que podríamos considerar `+` y `Number` como similares en cómo convierten de string a número, sin embargo sí existen diferencias en cómo procesan la información antes de que sea convertida a un número.

`toString` parsea de una diferente forma, pues no invoca a la función abstracta `toNumber`, checa las referencias si deseas conocer más detalles.

Dado ese preámbulo, la pregunta es, ¿qué es más óptimo `toString` o `toNumber` (la función abstracta que utilizan `+` y `Number`)?

Para resolver esa duda, hice este pequeño test.

```js
const parseInts = numbers => {
    let tmp;
    for (const n of numbers)
        tmp = parseInt(n);
}

const parseNumbers = numbers => {
    let tmp;
    for (const n of numbers)
        tmp = Number(n);
}

const parseNumbersPlus = numbers => {
    let tmp;
    for (const n of numbers)
        tmp = +n;
}

const fillArrayWithRandomValues = (arr, max, min=20) => {
    const N_ELEMENTS = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

    for (let i = 0; i < N_ELEMENTS; ++i)
        arr[i] = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`;
}

const test = (max_n_elements) => {
    const arr = [];

    fillArrayWithRandomValues(arr, max_n_elements);

    console.time("parsing with Number()");
    parseNumbers(arr);
    console.timeEnd("parsing with Number()");

    console.time("parsing with parseInt()");
    parseInts(arr);
    console.timeEnd("parsing with parseInt()");

    console.time("parsing with +");
    parseNumbersPlus(arr);
    console.timeEnd("parsing with +");
};

const tests = [10_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000, 100_000_000];

for (const t of tests) {
    console.log(`--------\nTesteo con ~${t} datos`);
    test(t);
    console.log("--------\n")
}
```

Ejecútalo y juzga tú mismo. Es probable que te salgan resultados diferentes si lo ejecutas con uno u otro motor de JS V8, spidermonkey o nodejs.

La razón de eso, es la implementación y optimización que cada motor tiene.

A grandes rasgos, podría decir que `parseInt` tiene mejor rendimiento. Sin embargo, esto depende del motor y de JIT. Por lo que para optimizar una función, ya sea `parseInt` o `Number`, habría que ejecutarla muchas veces para que JIT la detecte, haga su trabajo y la optimice.

**No importa mucho por lo tanto qué función utilices, sino qué tanto la utilices, y la implementación y optimización que tiene el motor de JS en el que estás ejecutando tu código**.

Referencias:

- [Operador `+`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator)
- [`Number()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor)
- [`parseInt()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix)